# Can/should some Objective-C questions also use the C tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Objective-C is a strict super set of C.  That is to say, absolutely anything that will work in C will also work exactly as is in Objective-C.  What's more, Objective-C projects can even seamlessly integrate pure C files.  This isn't necessarily all that common, but what is very common is significant chunks of pure C code in the middle of an Objective-C file.

I present this question as an example: [Creating a better NSLog](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/48204/creating-a-better-nslog)

Would a C language tag be appropriate/acceptable here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you have an [objective-c](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/objective-c) question in front of you and are considering adding a [c](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c) tag on it, ask yourself this question:

**Would someone who knows [c](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c) but not [objective-c](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/objective-c) be interested in reviewing this code, as if it was [c](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c)?**

Regarding your specific example question there, I think the answer is no. I say this mainly because of lines like these:

```
timeStampFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[timeStampFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"];
[timeStampFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
```

That doesn't look like C at all to me.

Comment: and .... what's this `@import` thing too...?

Comment: But as the posted answer points out, this exact bit of code could be accomplish in plain C and probably more efficiently.  Even if you don't know ObjC, it's pretty plain to see that snippet is trying to format a timestamp, which surely can be done in plain C.

Comment: @nhgrif But the *question* is about ObjC, not C. Language tags should be used according to the language in the question, not according to the language suggested to be used in answers.

Comment: The question is about the best way to accomplish a task in Objective-C.  Sometimes the best way to accomplish a task in Objective-C is by writing pure C code.  As far as I know, this is a very special case.  There are no questions about C++ where the answer could be to write the code in C instead of C++ because not everything that works in a .c file will work in a .cpp file, so you HAVE to know the differences between C++ and C to post an answer that will work for the question without recommending a different language.  The same isn't true for Objective-C.

Answer (score 4):

If you intend for the code to be polyglot, then use both tags. Otherwise, if you only want it to work as Objective-C, then just the [objective-c](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/objective-c) tag should be used.

Comment: This would be a fair comment if I were asking the question the other way around "Should some C questions use the Objective-C tag?"  But when we're talking about Objective-C and C, you can't really write code that's "just objective-c".  As I stated, anything written in C will work exactly as is in Objective-C.  This is code review, and if a person asking for a review of some Objective-C code is looking for the absolute most efficient way to do something, the answer will include a very deep dive in C sometimes.